# plugin was built with a different version of package crypto/internal/boring​

Tags: go, boringssl

I have a code in golang that is using buildmode plugins. I am building the main program and the plugins inside the same image (goboring/golang:1.15.8b5) and one after the other. When running the main program, as soon as it tries to load the plugins, I get the error:

```
E0319 14:27:38.417362   34123 daemon.go:639] loadVendorPlugins(): fail to load plugin /plugins/my_plugin.so: plugin.Open("/plugins/my_plugin"): plugin was built with a different version of package crypto/internal/boring​
```

This does not happen if I change the image to golang:1.15. Any idea why a different version for a package is found even if both are built in the same image? Why the base image might have an impact on this?

Comment: What do you mean by the "same image"? How exactly are you building these? Please create a [mre] showing how you encountered the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/sriov-network-operator/blob/master/Dockerfile.sriov-network-config-daemon, if I change the build image to goboring/golang:1.15.8b5, I get the error that I showed. As you can see in the Dockerfile, both _build-sriov-network-config-daemon and plugins are built inside the same container based on the same image. That's why I find it so weird

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, when using the buildmode=plugin, it is not strange to see this problem. The solution is to add the flag `-trimpath` to the go build, as explained here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27751#issuecomment-593082117